# Converting a list of tuples to a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples, series

I have a list of tuples which I want to convert to a Series.

```
return array2

[(0, 0.07142857142857142),
  (0, 0.07142857142857142),
  (1, 0.08333333333333333),
  (1, 0.3333333333333333),
  (1, 0.3333333333333333),
  (1, 0.08333333333333333),
  (3, 0.058823529411764705),
  (3, 0.058823529411764705)]
```

I attempt to do this by converting the list to a dictionary and then to a Series:

```
 a = pd.Series(dict(array2))
```

The resulting Series however, doesn't behave as I need it to.  It seems to drop `key:value` pairs (possibly arbitrarily?)

E.g.

```
return a

 0    0.071429
 1    0.083333
 3    0.058824
```

How would I obtain a series without dropping any key value pairs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by first column, then select second column for `Series`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(array2).set_index(0)[1]
print (a)
0
0    0.071429
0    0.071429
1    0.083333
1    0.333333
1    0.333333
1    0.083333
3    0.058824
3    0.058824
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Or create 2 lists and pass to `Series` contructor:

```
idx = [x[0] for x in array2]
vals = [x[1] for x in array2]

a = pd.Series(vals, index=idx)
print (a)
0    0.071429
0    0.071429
1    0.083333
1    0.333333
1    0.333333
1    0.083333
3    0.058824
3    0.058824
dtype: float64
```

Comment: HI, if I want a column of this tuples only... How to do that @jezrael

Answer (score 26):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and sequence unpacking:

```
idx, values = zip(*L)

a = pd.Series(values, idx)
```

With duplicate indices, as in your data, `dict` will not help as duplicate dictionary keys are not permitted: `dict` will only take the last value for every key supplied.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the * is needed, it appears the * is required @jpp

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you convert a list of tuples to a dictionary, Python drops all duplicate keys and only uses the last value for each key. This is necessary since each key can only appear once in a dictionary. So you need to use a method that preserves all the records. This will do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(array2, columns=['key', 'val'])
df = df.set_index('key')
a = df['val']
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
array2 = [
    (0, 0.07142857142857142),
    (0, 0.07142857142857142),
    (1, 0.08333333333333333),
    (1, 0.3333333333333333),
    (1, 0.3333333333333333),
    (1, 0.08333333333333333),
    (3, 0.058823529411764705),
    (3, 0.058823529411764705)
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(array2, columns=['key', 'val'])
df = df.set_index('key')
a = df['val']
print(a)
# key
# 0    0.071429
# 0    0.071429
# 1    0.083333
# 1    0.333333
# 1    0.333333
# 1    0.083333
# 3    0.058824
# 3    0.058824
# Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.transpose` to unpack the columns, then make a `pd.Series`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x, y = np.transpose(array2)
pd.Series(y, x)
```

Comment: Is this faster than `pd.Series.T` (transpose)?

Comment: Or, you could use `x, y = zip(*array2)` to save having to load Numpy.  Also, this preserves the type of the index (int).

Comment: Oh.  That has already been suggested by @jpp.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MultiIndex`

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L).to_frame()[1].reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[79]: 
0    0.071429
0    0.071429
1    0.083333
1    0.333333
1    0.333333
1    0.083333
3    0.058824
3    0.058824
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: out of box solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of tuples is

```
tuples = [(0, 0.07142857142857142),
  (0, 0.07142857142857142),
  (1, 0.08333333333333333),
  (1, 0.3333333333333333),
  (1, 0.3333333333333333),
  (1, 0.08333333333333333),
  (3, 0.058823529411764705),
  (3, 0.058823529411764705)]
```

I would use (explicit is better than implicit):

```
pd.Series([value for _, value in tuples], index=[index for index, _ in tuples])
```

However, I would also reconsider if the series data format is appropriate and meaningful: An index is actually meant to be like a dict, namely mapping a unique value to a value.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct answer, sometimes it is easier to create `pd.DataFrame` directly out of list of tuples, instead of creating `pd.Series` This is especially true if you need to work with multiple series later.

When skipping creating Series, you can have both tuple left and right value as the DataFrame columns, instead of index and column. This avoids some problems like having duplicate index keys, Nones, NaNs, in the tuple data.

Also, the code for creating DataFrame is shorter and easier to read.

Here is an example of how to go directly to DataFrame:

```py
# Prepare data as list of (value, timestamp) tuples
# Keep the order in mind
tvl_data = [(ps.total_equity, ps.calculated_at) for ps in state.stats.portfolio]
volume_data = [(t.get_volume(), t.executed_at) for t in state.portfolio.get_all_trades()]

# Convert to DataFrames without index
tvl = pd.DataFrame(tvl_data, columns=["tvl", "timestamp"])
volume = pd.DataFrame(volume_data, columns=["volume", "timestamp"])

# Merge DataFrames, index to a common index
df = pd.concat([tvl, volume]).set_index("timestamp")
display(df)
```

[image]

If you do not do this, your data is not clean, you are likely to encounter:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```